# Problem with javascript : url redirects http to https

Tags: magento-1.9, ssl

I am using Magento ver. 1.9.1.0 and theme is ShopShark ver.1.7.4.5 -> Milano

**site adding ssl**

In the theme file path add in one javascript

```
app/code/local/ShopShark/ThemeConfig/etc/config.xml
```

[image]

**I change to http to https but not working https in the link**

What is the problem and how should I solve this?

Comment: Is it a external java-script url ?

Comment: yes  external java-script url

Comment: Then it may be they are not having SSl. You can check it by hitting the JS url in browser with HTTPS directly.

Comment: yes i check it is have https it have it..

Comment: but i change the https it not working

Answer (score 0):

In this case open that JS url in browser and copy all content of that JS in your local file and copy that file in js folder and include that js file with the help of page.xml of your theme directory.

Comment: i change the config.xml file it not working

Comment: i change the code in the config.xml but no effect in the site

Comment: You have to copy that js file and put in your local folder

Comment: any change that file no effect.. even though i change the class name to change in the file no effect in the site that only i asking

Comment: i got the result url change in the datebase